# Filling missing values with null

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lodash

What is the best/cleanest solution to find those fields that are being missed in obj1 in comparison to unionObject and add the missing fields with value of null;
For instance object1:

```
  var object1= { id: '123',
          name: 'test1'              
    }
```

And unionObject is:

```
  var unionObject = { id: '124',
          name: 'test2',
          type: 'type2',
          files: 
           {
             http: 'test12.com',
             https: 'test2.com' 
           }
    }
```

So here object1 is missing files with fields http and https and type; so my desired output would be:

```
 var desiredOutput= { id: '123',
          name: 'test1',
          type: null,
          files: 
           {
             http: null,
             https: null 
           }
    }
```

Please note this is NOT my deiredoutput:

```
 var notDesiredOutput= { id: '123',
          name: 'test1',
          type: null,
          files: null              
    }
```

What is the best/cleanest way to do it in Node.JS; is there any module on NPM to do it in a clean way?

Thanks

Comment: I have a vanilla solution but it involves recursion. What happens if `files` property object has objects inside, should they be also copied with their properties as being null? So if you imagine the whole thing as a tree, only the leaves are nulls?

Comment: True! See the last two examples!

Comment: Might be over powered, but you could look at [diff: changes](https://github.com/flitbit/diff#changes). Probably useful if you need to change the behavior later.

Comment: It can be done also with an iteration and a queue. Basically add all missing attributes of the first object that are missing in the second in the queue and start looping over them. if any of them is an object, then add it to the queue and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. It uses lodash, but it's not strictly necessary. You could replace the `_.isUndefined` and `_.isPlainObject` with their plain JS equivalents.

```js
function inferFromUnion(obj, union) {
  Object.keys(union).forEach(function(key) {
    if (_.isUndefined(obj[key])) {
      if (_.isPlainObject(union[key])) {
        obj[key] = {};
        inferFromUnion(obj[key], union[key]);
      } else {
        obj[key] = null;
      }
    }
  });
}

var unionObject = {
  id: '124',
  name: 'test2',
  type: 'type2',
  files: {
    http: 'test12.com',
    https: 'test2.com'
  }
};

var object1 = {
  id: '123',
  name: 'test1'
};

inferFromUnion(object1, unionObject);

console.log(object1);
document.write(JSON.stringify(object1));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution, also do you know the async version of this function? I need to use async; I updated my question with my attempted version of your solution in async, but so far no success...

Comment: @Pasargad There is no need to make this async. Async in Node is to avoid blocking on I/O, but making this async would be useless.

Comment: I understand, but in the team that I'm working everyone believes Node is a non blocking language and only our code can block the execution, so everwhere we are using async functions and even this logic that I need to implement is inside async.each(objects, function (obj, callback) {// It needs to be implemented here inside async function},function(err){}); So your help is really appreciated

Comment: Maybe I need to have a separate question for async! I'm realy confused with async!